# Apps Script - how to get the correct headers range to set the value to a cell google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function response() {
  var url = 'https://api.zonda.exchange/rest/trading/ticker/BTC-PLN'
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.zonda.exchange/rest/trading/ticker/BTC-PLN');
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D4').setValue("hello");
}
```

Logs:

```
{ "status": "Ok", "ticker": { "market": { "code": "BTC-PLN", "first": { "currency": "BTC", "minOffer": "0.0000432", "scale": 8 }, "second": { "currency": "PLN", "minOffer": "5", "scale": 2 }, "amountPrecision": 8, "pricePrecision": 2, "ratePrecision": 2 }, "time": "1663016303747", "highestBid": "104000.28", "lowestAsk": "104232.99", "rate": "104300.04", "previousRate": "104232" } }
```

Comment: What's a headers range? Is anything like a Chicken Way?

Comment: {
"status": "Ok",
"ticker": {
"market": {
"code": "BTC-PLN",
"first": {
"currency": "BTC",
"minOffer": "0.0000432",
"scale": 8
},
"second": {
"currency": "PLN",
"minOffer": "5",
"scale": 2
},
"amountPrecision": 8,
"pricePrecision": 2,
"ratePrecision": 2
},
"time": "1663016303747",
"highestBid": "104000.28",
"lowestAsk": "104232.99",
"rate": "104300.04",
"previousRate": "104232"
}
}

Comment: I mean the value of the headers : "highestBid", "lowestAsk",e.t.c

Comment: I suppose that's intended to be an answer to my question but I'm still wondering what's a headers range?

Comment: So you wish know how to extract data from an object?

Comment: Yes if that gives me the value of 104000.28 in the cell of google sheets etc.

Comment: Please create a sample of the result sheet manually and show how it should look like.

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: the worksheet should look like this for the selected value : highestBid 104000.28 - I don't think you can add jpg here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getData() {
  const json = '{ "status": "Ok", "ticker": { "market": { "code": "BTC-PLN", "first": { "currency": "BTC", "minOffer": "0.0000432", "scale": 8 }, "second": { "currency": "PLN", "minOffer": "5", "scale": 2 }, "amountPrecision": 8, "pricePrecision": 2, "ratePrecision": 2 }, "time": "1663016303747", "highestBid": "104000.28", "lowestAsk": "104232.99", "rate": "104300.04", "previousRate": "104232" } }';
  let obj = JSON.parse(json);
  Logger.log(obj.ticker.highestBid);
  Logger.log(obj.ticker.lowestAsk);
}
```

---

```
Execution log
3:14:07 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:14:05 PM  Info    104000.28
3:14:05 PM  Info    104232.99
3:14:08 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

---

```
function getData() {
  const json = '{ "status": "Ok", "ticker": { "market": { "code": "BTC-PLN", "first": { "currency": "BTC", "minOffer": "0.0000432", "scale": 8 }, "second": { "currency": "PLN", "minOffer": "5", "scale": 2 }, "amountPrecision": 8, "pricePrecision": 2, "ratePrecision": 2 }, "time": "1663016303747", "highestBid": "104000.28", "lowestAsk": "104232.99", "rate": "104300.04", "previousRate": "104232" } }';
  let obj = JSON.parse(json);
  let o = Object.keys(obj.ticker).map(k => {
    if (typeof obj.ticker[k] !== 'object') {
      return [k, obj.ticker[k]];
    } else {
      return ["",""];
    }
  }).filter(e => e[0]);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.clearContents();
  o.unshift(["Key","Value"]);
  sh.getRange(1,1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

The is what my sheet output looks like

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| time | 1663016303747 |
| highestBid | 104000.28 |
| lowestAsk | 104232.99 |
| rate | 104300.04 |
| previousRate | 104232 |

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint - I will check it within 1-2 hours and let you know how it went.

Comment: I think I need to change the time to European - I don't know the unexpectet token message, line 9

Comment: What cell address?

Comment: Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier line: 8 file: Code.gs - Execution log

Comment: sorry i didn't copy all the code before

Comment: The second version will put it into a spreadsheet

Comment: I can see that everything is in your code and the address of cells sheets but I get this error Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier line: 8 file: Code.gs

Comment: @elbingerr [:sigh:] Don't copy Execution log and the next 4 lines. Delete it.

Comment: function response() {
  var url = 'https://api.zonda.exchange/rest/trading/ticker/BTC-PLN'
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.zonda.exchange/rest/trading/ticker/BTC-PLN');
Logger.log(response);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(response);
}

Comment: This is a simplified solution to my question that I have figured out on my own.

Comment: Now all I have to do is extract data from an object.